# Laravel, namespaces and PSR-4

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, psr-4

I'm trying to set up PSR-4 within a new Laravel 4 application, but I'm getting some troubles achieving what I want when it comes to build controllers.

Here's what I have now :

```
namespace MyApp\Controllers\Domain;

class DomainController extends \BaseController {

    public $layout = 'layouts.default';

    public function home() {
        $this->layout->content = \View::make('domain.home');
    }
}
```

I'm not so fond of using `\View`, `\Config`, `\Whatever` to use Laravel's classes. So I was wondering if I could put a `use Illuminate\View;` to be able to use `View::make` without putting a `\`.

Unfortunately, while doing this, I'm getting the following error : `Class 'Illuminate\View' not found`.

Could somebody help with this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is that `View` is not located in `Illuminate` namespace but in `Illuminate\View` namespace, so correct import would be not:

```
use Illuminate\View;
```

but

```
use Illuminate\View\View;
```

You can look at http://laravel.com/api/4.2/ to find out which namespace is correct for class you want to use

Comment: Sh** I need to get some more coffee this morning... Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming BaseController.php has a namespace of MyApp\Controllers\Domain

```
namespace MyApp\Controllers\Domain;

use View;

class DomainController extends BaseController {

    public $layout = 'layouts.default';

    public function home() {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('domain.home');
    }
}
```

If BaseController.php has other namespace, i.e MyApp\Controllers

```
namespace MyApp\Controllers\Domain;

use MyApp\Controllers\BaseController;
use View;

class DomainController extends BaseController {

    public $layout = 'layouts.default';

    public function home() {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('domain.home');
    }
}
```

If, for instance, you controller needs to use another base class from Laravel, lets say `Config`.

```
namespace MyApp\Controllers\Domain;

use MyApp\Controllers\BaseController;
use View;
use Config;

class DomainController extends BaseController {

    public $layout = 'layouts.default';

    public function home() {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('domain.home')->withName(Config::get('site.name'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of View::make() takes advantage of the Laravel facades. To properly reference the facade, instead of directly referencing the class that gets resolved out of the iOC container, I would use the following:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
```

This will reference the View facade that is being used when calling View::make()